Formatting time-series data for LSTM model
To my knowledge, LSTM models take 3D input data of the format (batch_size, timesteps, features).  But, when creating the batches, I've often seen them literally add a batch where the data is just shifted over by 1 in the original time-series (almost like a "moving window and/or walk-forward" method of sorts). However, wouldn't it be more optimal to take a bunch of random batches within the data of size timestep rather than merely shift the data by 1.
I feel that this would be better to prevent overfitting as the LSTM wouldn't just  be incrementally exposed to the dataset. Does this randomization happen internally?
Thank you!
Perhaps I am misunderstanding something about the LSTM, if so, please let me know!
